# What is this inversion?

Tags: grammar

Try I did. But I couldn't succeed.

I remember hearing this, but I don't understand the nuance of this inversion.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) *"**Try I did.** But I couldn't succeed."*

Your first sentence uses **complement preposing**. The complement *"try"* is preposed, and that complement is a **verb phrase**. This type of construction is used to apply focus on that you actually did try to do something. The main stress falls on the auxiliary verb *"did"*.

The following is a more basic version (i.e. the corresponding unemphatic default order clause):

- 2) *"I tried."*

In your version *"Try I did"*, the verb *"did"* was added to carry the stress since the default version #2 did not have an auxiliary verb in it--usually, an auxiliary verb is used for that purpose. There are usually some pragmatic constraints with the complement preposed versions (when compared to the more basic version).

For related info, there's the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), pages 1372-82, "3. Complement preposing".

Comment: +1... (Like the fact that you mentioned focus at the end; the opposite of the myth promulgated in EFL course books ...)